# How to used sed to modify string

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a string which is input string `./y1563/y1563.xls` want to convert it to a string output `y1563/y1563.txt`.

Comment: have you already tried a simple substitution?

Comment: NAME=./y1563/y1563.xls
VAR=`echo $NAME |sed -n 's/.xls//p'`                      I tried this..

Comment: please add some context to your question. I have the feeling that it is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: use `${VAR%.*}.txt`

Comment: I have file location which is ./y1563/y1563.xls and I want to create another file in $PWD/summary/y1563/y1563.txt. In order to do this, I need to get the "y1563/y1563.txt" from input string or current file location(./y1563/y1563.xls)

Answer (score 1):

You don't generally use `sed` to modify a string that you have ([according to your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551699/how-to-used-sed-to-modify-string#comment1024127_551699)) in a shell variable. At least not if all you want to do is to remove and/or replace the suffix of the string.

Instead,

```
NAME=./y1563/y1563.xls
NAME=${NAME%.xls}.txt    # remove .xls suffix, append .txt suffix
NAME=${NAME#./}          # remove ./ prefix (this may not be needed)
```

These (`${variable%pattern}` and `${variable#pattern}`) are [standard variable substitutions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) that removes suffix and prefix strings from a variable's value.

This would also work properly even if the `$NAME` value contains embedded newline characters.  Newlines are allowed in filenames, but since `sed` is a line-oriented editor, it would not handle such input correctly.